# Angular state not switching upon conditional change

Tags: html, angular, typescript

First, the Typescript code, followed by the HTML:

```
public checkValue() {
    let finalChoice = false;
    if (typeof this.formUser.permissionsTemplateID === undefined) {
      finalChoice = true;
    }
    return finalChoice;
  }
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="template">Permissions Template</label>
  <kendo-dropdownlist onChange="checkValue()" required name="template" [data]="templates" [(ngModel)]="formUser.permissionsTemplateID" [valuePrimitive]="true" textField="name" valueField="id"></kendo-dropdownlist>
  <div [hidden]="checkValue()" class="alert alert-danger">Please enter a valid permissions template.</div>
</div>
```

So, I'm fairly certain that I'm missing just one small detail here. I would like this warning mentioned when you first jump to the page (not the way I'd do it, but I have my orders) and then once someone selects from the drop down menu, then the error message should go away.

Comment: what if permissionsTemplateID is empty string, null or 0 is finalChoice should be false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first sight, when comparing the type of `this.formUser.permissionsTemplateID` you should check against a string (`'undefined'` instead of `undefined`):

```js
if (typeof this.formUser.permissionsTemplateID === 'undefined') {
```

Comment: That was it. I feel somewhat silly, but thank you!